# Vertices not merged (output from Kinect Fusion)

Tags: merge, kinect, kinect-sdk, vertices

I have a major problem right now. I was using the kinect fusion to capture a 3D scene and output it as an .OBJ file.

The output of the file looks something like this:

v 123 123 123

v 123 123 123

v 123 123 123

vn 321 321 321

vn 321 321 321

vn 321 321 321

f 1//1 2//2 3//3

Where v is the vertice, vn is normal, and f is the face. 3 vertices makes up a face, so the number of face is exacely 1/3 the number of vertices. But the problem is the output from kinect doesnt merge the vertices together. So after i import it into maya and merge them together, the number of vertice and vertice normals somehow become different!

Number of vertice after merge: 52837

Number of vertice normal after merge: 299997

Number of face after merge: 99999

How is that possible!? Shouldn't each vertice only have 1 vertice normal? Why is there more normal than vertices? The code that i wrote can only work if it follows that structure. Another way is to not merge the vertices together, but it may cause problems for me in the future.

Hope someone can help me T_T

Answer (score 0):

That's expected behavior.  Imagine you have two triangle making a quad. Unmerged, that's 6 vertices and  6 vertex normals.  After merging you will have 4 vertices  since the vertices at the diagonal corners are now united.  If the merged mesh is smoothed ( using *normals > soften edge* , for example) the shared vertices will also share vertex normals. If the mesh is faceted, you will still have 6 vertex normals even though you have 4 vertices.  That's probably where your extra numbers are coming from.

If the original geometry is clean the face count will remain the same - but bad geometry may include duplicate faces which should be eliminated by the merge, also reducing the vertex count.

You can artificially inflate the vert normal count by doing **mesh > triangulate** followed by **normals > Harden edge**.   This will cause the mesh to appear faceted. If you want smoothed normals (again **normals > soften edge**)  you should expect around 1 normal per vertex on average.